# How can I close this loop?

Tags: python, pipe, multiprocessing

I'm working on a Python script and I need some help.  This script runs just fine and gives me the results that I need, but the script doesn't exit because the p process is still running. How can I rectify this?

Let me say that in the function run_up this needs to be a while loop. This is a simplified version of what I'm actually trying to do and a for loop will not work for what I need.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe


def run_up(conn):
    i = 0
    while True:
        conn.send(i)
        i += 1
    conn.close()


def div_check():
    while True:
        v = parent_conn.recv()
        if v > 95:
            break
        elif v % 5 == 0:
            print '%i is divisible by 5' % v

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=run_up, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    div_check()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Should a child process be finished forcibly or should it be continued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event). So you could do `while not event.is_set()` instead of the `while True`. And in the other process, when you need to close it, do `event.set()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything works terrifically now

Answer (score 0):

Your function `run_up` has an infinite loop. That means the child process will never terminate, so you will be blocked on `join` forever.

If you know when to terminate it, that will fix your problem. Otherwise, you might need to do something like in @user3267581's answer in order to communicate between processes.